# UE4, setting relative angular velocity of object

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

## Context

I have been attempting to set the angular velocity of a frisbee in UE4. This is easy. However, UE4 adds an angular velocity through the center of mass of an object relative to the 'world-axis' and not relative to the axis of the frisbee. Below the 'World' axis is red, and the relative axis is green, and the frisbee is blue. The Left is a sideway cross-section of the frisbee if you were to throw it forward and angled upward, the right is a 3-D representation of the same throw.

## Issue

The issue is when the disc's relative axis and the 'world' axis are not the same. Since the disc rotates around the world axis, and not the relative axis, it will wobble whenever angular velocity is applied. ***Is there any way I can change to apply velocity via the local axis?***

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use `Transform Direction` on the axis to convert it world space before applying it as angular velocity?

Comment: @Ruzihm that did not change the issue - I added the new blueprint to the post with your modification

Comment: no that's not what I suggested - I'm referring to [`Transform Direction`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Transform/TransformDirection/index.html) and you'd use that to modify the (0,0,1000) and plug the result into `Set Physics Angular Velocity in Degrees`

Comment: Okay, updated the image - is this what you are suggesting? This still did not change the flight.

Comment: More like [this](https://i.imgur.com/4DaMMKH.png), pardon the mspaint job

Comment: @Ruzihm Just changed it to that ( updated the blueprint in the post) this made the disc not rotate at all, any ideas?

Comment: @Ruzhim, holy crap, yeah its working now - just changed the transform rotation to simply 1000 z rather than the out put from make vector. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the axis from local space to world space. Something along these lines:

[image: blueprint]